# How does the efficiency compare in these two SQL statements?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I'm updating a stored function that fetches a few columns from a table and does some other operations on it before returning it. Depending on an argument passed to the function, one value might be a special, hard-coded string, but 99% of the time, it's just going to be the column value instead.

I want this to be a future-proof solution, and can either handle it in a CASE statement inside the SELECT, or in procedural logic after the SELECT.

Which one is likely to be more efficient?

```
--Option 1
CREATE FUNCTION WeWantTheFunc(@arg1 NVARCHAR(40))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @my_variable NVARCHAR(255);

    SELECT @my_variable =   CASE
                                WHEN Column1 IS NULL AND @arg1 = 'Special Value'
                                THEN 'Something special'
                                ELSE Column1
                            END
    FROM my_table;

    RETURN @my_variable;
END

--Option 2
CREATE FUNCTION WeWantTheFunc(@arg1 NVARCHAR(40))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @my_variable NVARCHAR(255);

    SELECT @my_variable = column1
    FROM my_table;

    IF @my_variable IS NULL AND @arg1 = 'Special Value'
        SET @my_variable = 'Something special';

    RETURN @my_variable;
END
```

Comment: *which is better* - well, YOU can test that, can't you?! Run the function on a table with 1m rows with `statistics time on` and see; As an aside, neither is performant, use an inline table-valued function.

Comment: Quick question - if `my_table` has a few million rows, which of them do you want @my_variable to be? Note that the command above will do a full table scan every time, which means poor performance regardless. Anyway... in terms of performance, both do a full table scan (which is bad, but both do the same scan), and other basic variable manipulation (IF, SET etc without complex calculations or data reads) are effectively zero cost - so both will function about the same.

Comment: Query performance issues usually relate to how SQL Server optimizes WHERE clauses. But your example doesn't show any. So it's hard to help you beyond the advice @seanb offered. To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.